# How to get data from in this url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hi i want to get sysem requirements data in https://gamesystemrequirements.com/game/far-cry-6 how can do this on JS or react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's called Web Scraping,
You can check out tutorials and guides and learn it yourself

a bit of help :
https://www.edureka.co/blog/web-scraping-with-python/